# Plotting Wavefunction: TypeError: Only Size-1 Arrays Can be Converted to Python Scalars

Tags: python

I'm want to compute the wavefunction of an electron. Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
import cmath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(- np.pi, np.pi, 100, endpoint=True)
t = 0

def Wavefunction(x,t):
    return np.abs(cmath.exp(-1j*t)*cmath.cos(x)+cmath.exp(1j*t)*cmath.sin(x))**2

Amplitude =  np.vectorize(Wavefunction(x,t))
plt.plot(x, Wahrscheinlichkeit(x,t))
plt.show
```

When starting the program following error is shown *TypeError: Only Size-1 Arrays Can be Converted to Python Scalars*. I've seen that  *np.vectorize()* should solve the problem but for me, it didn't work.

Thank you for your help.
PS: Please don't be scared of this weird Wavefunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close: `np.vectorize` takes a function as an argument. Hence the correct code is:

```py
import cmath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(- np.pi, np.pi, 100, endpoint=True)
t = 0

def Wavefunction(x,t):
    return np.abs(cmath.exp(-1j*t)*cmath.cos(x)+cmath.exp(1j*t)*cmath.sin(x))**2

Amplitude =  np.vectorize(Wavefunction)
plt.plot(x, Wahrscheinlichkeit(x,t))
plt.show()
```

Quite often, `np.vectorize` is equivalently used as a decorator:

```py
import cmath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(- np.pi, np.pi, 100, endpoint=True)
t = 0

@np.vectorize
def Wavefunction(x,t):
    return np.abs(cmath.exp(-1j*t)*cmath.cos(x)+cmath.exp(1j*t)*cmath.sin(x))**2


plt.plot(x, Wahrscheinlichkeit(x,t))
plt.show()
```

Since you were trying to call `Wavefunction(x,t)`, it tried to call it before passing it to `np.vectorize`. That's why you got the same error.